# Is it possible to know why a question vanished from my "recent inbox messages"?

Tags: support, questions, comments, deleted-questions, search

I have been for several days discussing a question with the asker using comments. Yesterday a message appeared asking me if I wanted to move the discussion to a chat. I asked the question asker if he wanted to  do that and he said no, so we continued the discussion via comments. This morning the question has vanished. I can think of two possibilities to explain this removal, and of course there might be other reasons I have not thought of.

1. The asker removed the question.
2. Stack Exchange removed the question because we did not move the discussion to a chat.

I do not remember the title
of the question of the name of the asker. Is there a way for me to find out why the question vanished?

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/602798/2451) question?

Comment: Note that comments which have been moved to chat should be visible from your [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/487748/buzz).

Answer (score 2):

To answer the specific question, it is possible to view deleted posts once you reach [10,000 reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) and gain access to the [moderator tools](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). It will show which user deleted the post in the banner at the top, although it will not provide more explanation or context absent a comment from somebody like a moderator explaining why a post was deleted. There doesn't appear to be a way to search for deleted questions or answers posted by others, so you'd have to know the link to the post in question to see the banner once you get the rep to do so.

In this case, though, I checked every question deleted in the past 3 days and none of them have comments from you. So the post you're looking for isn't deleted, and the comment from @Qmechanic is probably the one you're after.

Comment: Thank you. This is the one. The reason I thought it was removed is that it is no longer appearing in the list "Recent inbox messages".

Comment: @Buzz When comments are moved to chat, the notifications are removed from the inbox.